# Get smtp response code using Nylas

Tags: smtp, email-client

Does anyone know how you can get a smtp response code for bounced emails using Nylas? I've looked at Nylas documentation but I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer.
Look at this, https://nylas.com/cloud/docs?ruby#sending_errors